# How can I get a custom processing status screen to show progress or records processed

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom process screen which works pretty much as expected, except that the status / monitor screen that pops up during processing doesn't show the progress, or the records processed as it does on other, stock processing screens.

Here's what a stock processing popup looks like:

[image]

And here's what my custom popup looks like.  It doesn't show 'Remaining' and pretty much just looks like this until it's finished:

[image]

And then shows this when finished:

[image]

Is there something I need to add to my processing screen to get this functionality?

Thanks much...

Comment: Have you had a chance to review the blog post here:
https://www.acumatica.com/blog/creating-custom-processing-screens-in-acumatica/

Comment: Yep.  In fact, that's what I went by when creating my processing screen.  Says nothing about that status monitor / popup screen - since that seems to be built in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your processing method are you using PXProcessing.SetCurrentItem(object) to set the current processing item and then the PXProcessing.SetProcessed() or PXProcessing.SetError(ExceptionObject) to set the status of the current processing item.

Example:

```
public PXProcessing<SOLine> linesToBeProcessed;

protected virtual void ProcessOrderLines(List<SOLines> lines)
{
    foreach (SOLine line in lines)
    {
        PXProcessing<SOLine>.SetCurrentItem(line);
        try
        {
            //logic

            PXProcessing<SOLine>.SetProcessed();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PXProcessing<SOLine>.SetError(ex);
        } 
    }
}
```

Note: The DACNAME to use in these methods is the main DAC used in the PXProcessing view that was declared.

Comment: That's what I was missing.  Thanks much, Jean Claude!...

Answer (score 0):

This is a chunk of code from our Acumatica Surveys project that depicts how we control the messaging for various types.
Notice the SetInfo, SetWarning, and SetError
Let me know if this helps?

```
/// <summary>
    /// This method will create a new collector record and invoke a notification on it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="surveyUser"></param>
    /// <param name="graph"></param>
    /// <param name="surveyCurrent"></param>
    /// <param name="surveyUserList"></param>
    /// <param name="filter"></param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// </remarks>
    /// <returns>
    ///     Whether or not an error has occured within the process which is used by the main calling process to throw a final exception at the end of the process
    /// </returns>
    private static bool SendNew(SurveyUser surveyUser, SurveyCollectorMaint graph, Survey surveyCurrent, List<SurveyUser> surveyUserList, SurveyFilter filter) {
        bool errorOccurred = false;
        try {
            string sCollectorStatus = (surveyUser.UsingMobileApp.GetValueOrDefault(false)) ?
                                       SurveyResponseStatus.CollectorSent : SurveyResponseStatus.CollectorNew;
            graph.Clear();
            SurveyCollector surveyCollector = new SurveyCollector {
                CollectorName =
                    $"{surveyCurrent.SurveyName} {PXTimeZoneInfo.Now:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}",
                SurveyID = surveyUser.SurveyID,
                UserID = surveyUser.UserID,
                CollectedDate = null,
                ExpirationDate = CalculateExpirationDate(filter.DurationTimeSpan),
                CollectorStatus = sCollectorStatus
            };
            surveyCollector = graph.Collector.Insert(surveyCollector);
            graph.Persist();
            SendNotification(surveyUser, surveyCollector);
            if (sCollectorStatus == SurveyResponseStatus.CollectorSent) {
                PXProcessing<SurveyUser>.SetInfo(surveyUserList.IndexOf(surveyUser), Messages.SurveySent);
            } else {
                PXProcessing<SurveyUser>.SetWarning(surveyUserList.IndexOf(surveyUser), Messages.NoDeviceError);
            }
        } catch (AggregateException ex) {
            errorOccurred = true;
            var message = string.Join(";", ex.InnerExceptions.Select(e => e.Message));
            PXProcessing<SurveyUser>.SetError(surveyUserList.IndexOf(surveyUser), message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorOccurred = true;
            PXProcessing<SurveyUser>.SetError(surveyUserList.IndexOf(surveyUser), e);
        }
        return errorOccurred;
    }
```

Comment: That helps a lot.  Thank you so much, Robert! ;D